# Select query with IN and TEXT field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm new for MySQL. I'm having follwoing Database. I want to fetch the data using movie id. Here movie is *TEXT* field.

```
+----------+---------+-------+
|    id    |  genre  | movie |
+----------+---------+-------+
|    1     |    1    |   1   |
|    2     |    8    |   2   |
|    3     |    3    |  1,2  |
|    4     |    2    |   2   |
|    5     |    8    |  2,1  |
|    6     |    3    | 1,2,3 |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

I used following query,

```
SELECT id FROM t_table WHERE movie IN (2)
```

It's giving, id(2,4,5). But I want (2,3,4,5,6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below query. Used LIKE operator in where clause.

```
SELECT id FROM t_table WHERE movie LIKE "2" OR movie LIKE "2,%" OR movie LIKE "%,2" OR movie LIKE "%,2,%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find_in_set` method instead:

```
select id from t_table where find_in_set('2', movie) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest query that i can give to you using a LIKE operator in SQL.

```
SELECT id FROM t_table WHERE movie LIKE "2" OR movie  LIKE "%,2," OR movie  LIKE "2,%" OR movie  LIKE "%,2%"
```

Which simply means that there can be 4 conditions in the column:

movie column has only 2 in it 
   movie column may have ,2, in it
   movie column has only 2, in it
   movie column has only ,2 in it

Useful link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Above all mentioned queries are good but will fail when you will have data like '1, 2, 3' or ' 2' etc.
If you have to handle from the OR clause then you have to keep on adding OR clauses as you encounter scenarios and will end up having a long query.

My recommendation is using regular expressions which are meant for this purpose, are powerful and succinct. For you I have devised on - `select * from MOVIES where REGEXP_LIKE (mov, ',?(^[^2]*2[^2]*$)(\s|\S)?,?');`
Give a try.